# Can you search for most active users in a Slack Channel?

Tags: slack

I want to find the most **active users** in a workspace that are **interested in a certain subject** eg : **Jira**.

I thought of either search who is most active in a specific channel or type certain words in chats.
Should I use the api, or is there already a tool for this or just a clever query that I have missed?

I have looked into : The [search message api method.](https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages) But I am not sure if it is overkill to write rest client for this use-case.

I guess I am looking for a **aggregation method** like SQL count by , group by having etc in the [Slack Search query language](https://slack.com/intl/en-se/help/articles/202528808-Search-in-Slack) .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the search API because you need to search for something first to use it, when you need to basically index all the content yourself.

Probably the most direct way would be to search a channel your interested in, collecting messages from (and messages to) a person, counting the whole time by their unique id.

Comment: Yes I thought making a search for eg : Jira or feature in the Jira slack channel through api. Get the json respons and do it all by myself. But if someone knew of better way.

Comment: Seems like that would be the most straightforward way, but maybe you could do some kind of recursive search starting with your own username?